# An example of a beautiful proof that would be accessible at the high school level?

Tags: mathematics-education, soft-question, examples, teaching, big-list

The background of my question comes from an observation that what we teach in schools does not always reflect what we practice.  Beauty is part of what drives mathematicians, but we rarely talk about beauty in the teaching of school mathematics.

I'm trying to collect examples of good, accessible proofs that could be used in middle school or high school. Here are two that I have come across thus far:

(1) Pick's Theorem:  The area, $A,$ of a lattice polygon, with boundary points $B$ and interior points $I$ is $A = I + B/2 - 1.$

I'm actually not so interested in verifying the theorem (sometimes given as a middle school task) but in actually proving it.  There are a few nice proofs floating around, like one given in "Proofs from the Book" which uses a clever application of Euler's formula.  A very different, but also clever proof, which Bjorn Poonen was kind enough to show to me, uses a double counting of angle measures, around each vertex and also around the boundary.  Both of these proofs involve math that doesn't go much beyond the high school level, and they feel like real mathematics.

(2) Menelaus Theorem:  If a line meets the sides $BC,$ $CA,$ and $AB$ of a triangle in the points $D, E,$ and $F$ then $(AE/EC) (CD/DB) (BF/FA) = 1.$ (converse also true)  See: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Generalization/Menelaus.shtml, also for the related Ceva's Theorem.

Again, I'm not interested in the proof for verification purposes, but for a beautiful, enlightening proof.  I came across such a proof by Grünbaum and Shepard in Mathematics Magazine.  They use what they call the Area Principle, which compares the areas of triangles that share the same base (I would like to insert a figure here, but I do not know how. -- given triangles $ABC$ and $DBC$ and the point $P$ that lies at the intersection of $AD$ and $BC,$ $AP/PD = \operatorname{Area} (ABC) / \operatorname{Area}(DBC).$)  This principle is great-- with it, you can knock out Menelaus, Ceva's, and a similar theorem involving pentagons.  And it is not hard-- I think that an average high school student could follow it; and a clever student might be able to discover this principle themselves.

Anyway, I'd be grateful for any more examples like these.  I'd also be interested in people's judgements about what makes these proofs beautiful (if indeed they are-- is there a difference between a beautiful proof and a clever one?) but I don't know if that kind of discussion is appropriate for this forum.

**Edit**: I just want to be clear that in my question I'm really asking about proofs you'd consider to be beautiful, not just ones that are neat or accessible at the high school level.  (not that the distinction is always so easy to make...)

Comment: Surely you know the books ''Math! Encounters with Undergraduates'', ''Math Talks for Undergraduates'' and ''The beauty of doing Mathematics'' by Serge Lang. They were written with your same intention.

Comment: @quid: Thanks.
@Giuseppe:  I really like Lang's book.  But one thing that strikes me, both with his book and a few others I've read on the beauty of mathematics-- they seem to be fairly general.  More like the experience you would get of beauty by visiting a museum, rather than the beauty you would experience in learning to paint yourself. Thanks for the other references, I will look at them.

Comment: I remember Lang giving a talk at Caltech supposedly aimed at undergraduates, but far more advanced. Lang called on a postdoc in the front row, apparently thinking he was a student, and the postdoc couldn't answer. At one point, he wrote out a complicated formula, and challenged Prof. Ramakrishnan, "Do you teach your students this?" "No." "So you see, Caltech is not better than anywhere [sic] else." After a bit more, he went back to the formula and corrected a sign. Ramakrishnan called out, "That, we teach."

Comment: Even the notion of proof may not be accessible at high school level

Comment: @Muro:  Why do you say that?

Comment: In the US, most high school mathematics classes are not based on proofs. Theorems are introduced without reference to proof. Only in a few limited situations are students asked to prove anything, such as in some geometry classes and some calculus classes. Instead, high school math classes concentrate on introducing objects, their properties, and how to manipulate those objects. Finding neat accessible proofs to show them is reasonable, but this is very different from finding neat accessible math to show them. E.g., I think the Chaos Game is accessible, but few students can handle the proofs. 

Comment: As far as I remember, the thing I liked the most in high school maths (age of 14) was the so called Ruffini's rule: $(x-a)$ divides a polynomial $P(x)$ if and only if $P(a)=0$. It looked to me so incredibly easy and so full of consequences. I hope they still learn it with a proof.

Comment: Here is a completely different proof of Pick's theorem:

http://mathoverflow.net/questions/46883/examples-of-using-physical-intuition-to-solve-math-problems/46924#46924

Comment: +1 Pietro.  One of the cornerstones of high school math.

Comment: @DouglasZare, what is the Chaos Game?

Comment: @LSpice: This is one recipe for approximating a fractal. Start with 3 fixed points A, B, and C. Let point $P_0$ be arbitrary, then let $P_{n+1}$ be the midpoint of $AP_n, BP_n,$ or $CP_n$ each with probability $1/3$. Sierpinski's triangle emerges. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_game

Comment: regarding the first paragraph of your post, I would like to say that one should make a change in elementary school math education then in high school level we can ecpect students enjoy our beautiful proofs and beautiful theorems. Pleasee see my Math Educator Se post below:

Comment: https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/20950/is-it-a-good-idea-for-elementary-school-students-to-observe-and-discover-the-ci

Answer (score 79):

Extending on Ralph's answer, there is a similar very neat proof for the formula for $Q_n:=1^2+2^2+\dots+n^2$. Write down numbers in an equilateral triangle as follows:

```
    1
   2 2    
  3 3 3
 4 4 4 4
```

Now, clearly the sum of the numbers in the triangle is $Q_n$. On the other hand, if you superimpose three such triangles rotated by $120^\circ$ each, then the sum of the numbers in each position equals $2n+1$. Therefore, you can double-count $3Q_n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}(2n+1)$. $\square$

(I first heard this proof from János Pataki).

How to prove formally that all positions sum to $2n+1$? Easy induction ("moving down-left or down-right from the topmost number does not alter the sum, since one of the three summand increases and one decreases"). This is a discrete analogue of the Euclidean geometry theorem "given a point $P$ in an equilateral triangle $ABC$, the sum of its three distances from the sides is constant" (proof: sum the areas of $APB,BPC,CPA$), which you can mention as well.

How to generalize to sum of cubes? <strike>Same trick on a tetrahedron.</strike> EDIT: there's some way to generalize it to higher dimensions, but unfortunately it's more complicated than this. See the comments below.

If you wish to tell them something about "what is the fourth dimension (for a mathematician)", this is an excellent start.

Comment: The proof of that identity I like the most, is: start with 6 right parallelepipeds of size k x k x 1. Arrange them as the lateral walls of a parallelepiped with exterior size (2k+1) x (k+1) x k and interior size (2k-1) x (k-1) x k (a house with neither floor nor ceiling, made n by $6k^2$ cubic bricks). Do this for k from 1 to n: since the exterior size of the k-th object is equal to the interior size of the (k+1)-th one up to a rotation,  the result is a set of matrioskas that fit together into a solid parallelepiped of size (2n+1) x (n+1) x n, which is also 6 times the sum of the $n$ squares.

Comment: @Frederico: Careful. The sum of cubes does **not** correspond to a tetrahedron, but rather a pyramid.  (Which does not have this nice symmetry)  However the slightly modified sum $$Q_N^'=\sum_{n=1}^N n\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^N n^3+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^N n^2$$ will correspond to a tetrahedron.  By using this symmetry we find $$Q_N^' = \frac{1}{4} (3N+1)\left(\frac{N(N+1)(N+2)}{6}\right)$$ since each entry will be $3N+1$ and the tetrahedral numbers are $\binom{N+3}{3}=\frac{N(N+1)(N+2)}{6}$.  From here we can deduce that $$\sum_{n=1}^N n^3=\frac{(N^2+N)^2}{4}.$$   

Comment: In short, you won't have a nice generalization of the solution for $n=2$ to higher dimensions.  Such a generalization is not expected either since Faulhaber's Formula is not so simple. 

Comment: @Eric Oh, you're right. :( What a pity, it would've been an even neater generalization.

Comment: Cool.  Both the example and the follow up comments.

Comment: BTW, computing the general sum $1^k + \dots + n^k$ is a nice exercise in discrete calculus.

Comment: This is so nice, I'm so impressed! After all my school and university studies, this is the first time I learn how one can prove this equality in such a simple and beautiful way. My shame: I always memorized it and thought an induction is a best way to explain. For $k \geq 2$ I see that the "geometrical" proof is not as nice. Are there any other beautiful proofs for higher dimensions?

Comment: Glad you appreciate it - I like it for the same reason. I don't think there is an easy formula for higher dimensions: since the Bernoulli numbers show up in the final formula, any procedure to prove it should somehow "encode" them. The best proof I know for a generic dimension relies on the identity $ (n+1)^{a+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n} ((k+1)^{a+1}-k^{a+1}) = \sum_k \sum_{d=0} \binom{a+1}{d}k^d$, which can be used to express $\sum_k k^a$ (unknown) in terms of $(n+1)^{a+1}$ and sums of lower powers (known by induction).

Answer (score 58):

The theorem of "[friends and strangers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorem_on_friends_and_strangers)": the [Ramsey number $R(3,3)=6$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem#Example%3A_R.283.2C3.29.3D6).
Not only can the proof be understood by high-school students, a proof can be discovered
by students at that level via something akin to the Socratic method.
First students can establish the bound $R(3,3) > 5$ by 2-coloring the edges of $K_5$:

          
[image: R33]
Then they can reason through that a 2-coloring of the edges of $K_6$ must contain a monochromatic triangle,
and so $R(3,3)=6$: in every group of six, three must be friends or three must be strangers.

After this exercise, an inductive proof of the 2-color version of Ramsey's theorem is in reach.

An added bonus here is that one quickly reaches the frontiers of mathematics: $R(5,5)$ is unknown!
It can be a revelation to students that there *is* a frontier of mathematics.  And then one can tell the
Erdős story about $R(6,6)$, as recounted [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem#Ramsey_numbers). :-)

Comment: R(3,3)=6 sticks in my memory as the one time I managed to explain mathematics to a non-mathematical friend in the pub

Comment: @Yemon: Yes, great pub-material! Especially if there are matchsticks or toothpicks available. :-) And yet still quite beautiful, perhaps not $R(3,3)$ alone, but certainly $R(r,s)$.  It is deep, after all: order cannot be avoided.

Comment: This might be apocryphal, but I've read a story about a sociologist who was surprised to discover such patterns of friendship or non-friendship among his subjects, and pondering the deep psychological origins. If true, a wonderful argument for the need for math literacy.

Comment: @Thierry: It would be nice if this interesting story could be tracked down and verified!

Comment: From Jacob Fox's lecture notes: "In the 1950’s, a Hungarian sociologist S. Szalai studied friendship relationships between children. He observed that in any group of around 20 children, he was able to ﬁnd four children who were mutual friends, or four children such that no two of them were friends. Before drawing any sociological conclusions, Szalai consulted three eminent mathematicians in Hungary at that time: Erdős, Turán and Sós. A brief discussion revealed that indeed this is a mathematical phenomenon rather than a sociological one."

Comment: Re the Szalai story: $R(4,4) = 18$.

Comment: Thanks Joseph, I might even have first read about it on MO!

Comment: I finally tracked down where I must have read about Szalai's story for the first time: N. Alon and M. Krivelevich's article on extremal combinatorics in the Princeton's companion. Also available at: http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~krivelev/papers.html

Comment: There being many Alon and Krivelevich papers at @ThierryZell's link, the specific one referenced is [Alon and Krivelevich - Extremal and probabilistic combinatorics](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~krivelev/PCM.ps).

Answer (score 47):

Euler's [Bridges of Konigsberg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridges_of_Konigsberg) problem. You can give it to students for five minutes to play with, watch them get annoyed, and then offer them the classical simple and beautiful impossibility proof. I think a lot of high school students, and even bright middle school students, would be totally convinced.

Comment: Yes! A read about that example in one of Martin Gardner's books at about that age.


Answer (score 43):

The proof, by counting inversions, that you can't interchange the 14 and 15 in the 15 puzzle, just by sliding, is accessible to high-school students, introduces important ideas, and might be found beautiful.

Answer (score 32):

Two of my favorites: (1) The parameterization of all primitive Pythagorean triples; (2) The formula for the $n$th Fibonacci number in terms of the golden ratio $\phi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$, with the corollary that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \longrightarrow \infty} F_n/F_{n-1} = \phi$.

Comment: I share Jesse views... I talked with high school student on Fibonacci according to:
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/33911/why-linear-algebra-is-funor

Answer (score 32):

The trefoil knot is non-trivial.

Proof:
It has a tricoloring:

[image] [<sup>(source)</sup>](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6a/Tricoloring.png)

And the existence of a tricoloring is preserved by Reidermeister moves. QED

Comment: +1 because it is so obviously technically uncomprehensible to a high school student (at myn hiogh school) yet plausibly beautiful, and beautifully plausible.

Comment: @Roy: I disagree with you. I don't think that this is incomprehensible to high school students. The notion of knot is pretty intuitive, and it's very easy to explain what a tricoloring is. Also, the Reidemeister moves are pretty easy things to explain (ok -- I'm not talking about the actual proof that they generate everything). The most difficult aspect of the argument is probably to convince a high school student that there is *need* for proof. Namely, isn't the trefoil obviously non-trivial!? For that, it might be good to show them some monster unknots first...

Comment: When I was shown the Reidemeister moves in school, several of my classmates and I made the objection, in essence, that it wasn't clear that they generated everything.  Worse, since we didn't have topology to work with, we didn't really have a "real" definition to compare it with, so it felt to us that the real issues were being swept under the rug.

Comment: I’ve never performed the experiment, but I think it should be possible to explain the completeness of the reidemeister moves to a grade schooler.  Ingredients: a knot made of wire and a flashlight to make its shadow.  First by shining the light, illustrate that the projection generally has only transverse double points; explain that for this to fail either the light ray must be tangent to the knot or must pass through three points; either can be avoided by jiggling a little.  Then move the flashlight around; illustrate that in 1-parameter families one sees no worse than cusps and triple points

Comment: ... explain that to see anything worse, the light must be twice tangent or pass through four points or... and again you jiggle to separate the phenomena.  (If you’re feeling exceptionally honest, I suppose you could mention that it will be many years before they learn the mathematics of jiggling.)

Answer (score 29):

Going by the parameters of the question, I don't see why the proof would necessarily need to be of a sophisticated theorem. I think Euclid's proof of the infinitude of primes is beautiful and definitely accessible to a high school audience. Having given the proof, one might reflect on some of its features that generalize to many other contexts, like proof by contradiction or the ability to use a clever construction to avoid infinite enumeration.

Comment: No! Do not use this proof as an occasion to talk about proof by contradiction.  Euclid's proof of this proposition was not by contradiction. The conventional practice of rearranging it into a proof by contradiction not only adds an extra complication that serves no purpose, but also leads to confusions such as the belief that if you multiply the first n primes and add 1, the result is always prime. See the paper by me and Catherine Woodgold on this: "Prime Simplicity", _Mathematical Intelligencer_, autumn 2009, pages 44--52.

Comment: (I fully agree that this proof is an excellent example for high-school students.)

Comment: It IS by contradiction, just not the kind of contradiction we have in mind.

Comment: To complete Michael Hardy's comment, Euclid's original proof proves the following statement: given any finite list of primes, we can extend the list by finding a prime not in the list. (Proof: multiply the primes in the list and add one; any prime factor of this new number is a prime not in the original list.) So it's a constructive way of taking a list of primes and producing another prime; we don't have to assume that the original list was "all the primes" (as in the contradiction proof) or that they were the first n primes.

Comment: It's certainly a great proof -- certainly immediately convincing.  For some reason, it always irritated me.  I've thought on and off over the years why this is.  The only thing I can think of is that, while it is constructive, it is also outrageously inefficient.  Now at the time I learned this, no one that I knew was even talking in those terms, so maybe it's just some instinct that I had.  I really wish I liked it more.  G.H. Hardy did, right?  You can't argue with that.

Answer (score 26):

[Cantor's diagonal argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument).

The warm-up could be an equally beautiful proof, namely that the [rationals are countable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3ADiagonal_argument.svg).

Comment: I am a bit torn on this one. At least I believe before one would have to also prove, say, that the cardinality of the rationals is equal to that of the naturals (and/or related things). Because if not the 'insight' that there are more reals than naturals might seem too 'obvious' to make a proof enlightening. 

Comment: But the enumeration proving that the rationals are countable is also almost as beautiful as the diagonal argument! Perhaps they could be combined.

Comment: Yes, I agree; combined it could be very interesting. I should have made my agreement clearer in my first comment; sorry about that.  

Comment: The counting-rationals argument loses some appeal when you have to deal properly with skipping the non-reduced fractions.  The visual proof of course establishes that $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \cong \mathbb{N}$ as sets, and the countability of $\mathbb{Q}$ follows by applying an unrelated lemma on cardinality of surjective images.  Glossing over a lemma like that seems exactly like what a beautiful proof (especially an *exemplary* proof) should avoid.

Comment: There is a simple bijection between the positive rationals and positive integers shown by the fusc function. Let $f(n)$ be the number of ways of representing $n$ as a sum of powers of $2$ with at most $2$ copies of each power. $f(4)=3$ since $4=4,2+2,2+1+1$. The sequence $\{f(n)\}_{n=0} = \{1,1,2,1,3,2,3,1,4,...\}$. Over natural numbers $n$, $g(n) = f(n-1)/f(n)$ hits each positive rational precisely once. See also the Calkin-Wilf tree, how Euclid's algorithm reduces relatively prime ordered pairs. The sequences of numerators and denominators in order are offset copies of $\{f(n)\}$.

Comment: What Douglas Zare said is nicely explained in the 1999 paper *Recounting the Rationals* (http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/website/recounting.pdf) by Calkin and Wilf. Some people have felt (http://blog.plover.com/math/recounting.html) that it's a good "first math paper" to read.

Answer (score 24):

Seeing the struggle of many students with standard trigonometry,
I especially like the rational parametrization of $x^2+y^2=1$
(which is equivalent to listing all Pythagorean triples) by
starting from $\sin^2\phi+\cos^2\phi=1$ and then using
$$
\sin\phi=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}, \quad
\cos\phi=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}, \qquad t=\tan\frac{\phi}2.
$$
Note that the formulas are usually used in the context of
integration of rational expressions in sine and cosine.

At the same time, a more general "geometric" argument (applicable to
general quadratics), due to Bachet (1620), is still at school level.
Namely, fix a single rational point on the curve, $(x _ 0,y _ 0)$ say,
and consider the intersection points of the curve and straight
lines $y-y_0=t(x-x_0)$ with rational slope $t$ passing through the point.

A beauty here is because of variety of different geometric and analytic
methods for solving a classical  arithmetic problem.

Comment: Since coordinate geometry was invented after 1620 I wonder how Bachet could have done that.

Comment: Franz, I will be definitely happier if you are a little bit more constructive in your critisism: you seem to be the right person to explain why the method is usually attributed to Bachet!

Answer (score 19):

The Gale-Sharpley stable marriage theorem, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem .

The algorithm and its proof are very much accessible to school students. Despite its innocuous look, the algorithm is not easy at all to invent.

On a similar note, Hall's theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem#Graph_theory . This looks like a recreational puzzle but actually is closer to university mathematics than everything done in high school.

Here is another combinatorial exercise which, properly presented, does not even look like mathematics: [the round track puzzle](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h44152p279550). The thing I don't like about it is that the standard "gotcha" proof (explained in the usual, informal way) requires a bit too much concentration to understand - some students might fail at it and take it as an example that mathematical proofs are something one either believes or not, rather than something one can check. Of course, one can formalize the proof, but this requires quite an amount of time in a high school class. [Update, a decade later: I have written an expanded version of the solution up as the solution to Exercise 5.2.4 in [my Fall 2020 Math 235 notes](https://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/%7Egrinberg/t/20f/mps.pdf).]

Comment: I’ll point out that the “combinatorial exercise” is actually useful. Assume that we are given a sequence $s_1,\dots,s_n$ of symbols of arities $a_1,\dots,a_n\ge0$, respectively. It is easy to see that if we can arrange them into a well-formed term, then $\sum_ia_i=n-1$. The exercise says that, conversely, if this identity holds, then there exists a (unique) cyclic permutation of the string $s_1\dots s_n$ which is a valid term in Polish (prefix) notation. Among other things, this allows you to count the well-formed terms consisting of $n$ symbols.

Comment: Nice! I think the following proof is another application of this exercise: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=2385164#p2385164 .

Answer (score 19):

The proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational is a nice example of proof by contradiction.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of that one.  Just curious, do you really find the proof beautiful (as opposed to slick, cool, or something like that)?

Comment: @Manya My conception of beauty has changed since I first saw that proof. At that time, I did indeed consider it quite beautiful. Now, however, it's so embedded in me that it's hard to appreciate its beauty.

Comment: How about the geometric proof (incommensurability of side and diagonal of a square) rather than the arithmetic proof?

Comment: @euklid345 What about it?

Comment: Also: the proof of the irationality of the golden ratio $\phi$. If $\phi=p/q$ with $0 < q < p$ then also $\phi=q/(p-q)$ and $0 < p-q < q$...

Comment: @Pietro,Euklid345: What Pietro gives IS essentially
the geometric proof already known to the Greeks, only
in other language. It also works for sqrt(2) (and, if
I recall correctly, for all numbers a+b*sqrt(c) with
a,b,c rational?).

Comment: I guess it depends on how it's presented.  In my experience, it mainly started out "suppose (a/b)^2 = 2 and a/b is in lowest terms", and then derived a contradiction, showing that a/b was not in lowest terms.  Invariably, students would respond, "Well, then *put* it in lowest terms."  It just wasn't convincing.  I always felt that casting the argument in terms of prime factorization was more convincing, but to be honest, I'm not convinced that I saw a lot of students being astonished at this, as I had been.  There's a certain amount of irreducible sophistication here.

Comment: @Quinn: in that case, I suggest trying to invent your own proof, and then make it as pretty as you possibly can. 

Comment: It is **not** a proof by **contradiction** - it is a proof of a **negation** : $\sqrt{2}=p/q\Rightarrow\bot$.

Comment: To expand on what Paul Taylor said: to prove a negation $\neg p$, "assume $p$ is *true* ... derive falsity". A proof by contradiction of $p$: "assume $p$ is *false* ... derive falsity". The difference is that the second method uses the law of the excluded middle ($\neg \neg p \Rightarrow p$), whereas the first is still valid in intuitionistic logic. See Andrej Bauer's essay: http://math.andrej.com/2010/03/29/proof-of-negation-and-proof-by-contradiction/

Comment: @PaulTaylor Some proofs really are proofs by contradiction under that definition.  (For example, a student may start with "Assume that $\sqrt{2}$ is not irrational.  That means it is rational.  So...")  Thus, a more correct statement is: "A proof exists that avoids a certain logical non-intuitionistic axiom."  But this is about teaching high school students beautiful proofs.  Are you really going to tell such a student "it is not a proof by contradiction"? If so, why stop there?  One could say: "It is not a proof of a negation, it is a *fill in the blank, weaker fragment* proof."

Comment: @PaceNielsen: No. Please read the  blog post by Andrej Bauer that Todd Trimble cited, or his better and famous [*Five Stages of Accepting Constructive Mathematics*](https://math.andrej.com/2016/10/10/five-stages-of-accepting-constructive-mathematics/).

Comment: @PaulTaylor I have read it.  I think it is a little too pedantic about negation, since most people work with classic full logic.  If we are going to worry about negation to that extent, why not worry about deeper meanings of $\Rightarrow$, etc...

Comment: @PaceNielsen: when studying logics of various kinds, one might "worry" about $\Rightarrow$, but this discussion was about "proof by contradiction" vs "proof of negation", which are distinguished by what happens with $\lnot$. Someone who "works with classic full logic" thinks that $\lnot\lnot\phi$ is the same as $\phi$ and therefore *cannot see the difference*. Just like a colour-blind person cannot see the difference between red and green. So which is which? *Rational* numbers are defined *without* using negation, *irrationality* is *derived* from that by putting $\lnot$ in front.

Comment: @PaceNielsen: ok, you could respond by saying that $\alpha$ is *irrational* (as the primitive notion) if $\forall p q.\alpha\neq p/q$. Taking $\neq$ (apartness) is the primitive, instead of $=$, is appropriate for $\mathbb R$ since  it is Hausdorff but not discrete, whereas $\mathbb N$ is both. The problem with that is that Euclid's argument depends on using induction in $\mathbb N$, whether you go via unique factorisation or directly.

Comment: The discussion in [this question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/462001) came to the conclusion that this positive definition of irrationality (or apartness-from-rationals) is best understood in terms of continued fractions.

Answer (score 16):

The [Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). The first time I saw this was my senior year in high school and it completely blew me away. All you need is a notion of what an algorithm is and very basic logic (enough to recognize that assuming $A$ and deriving $\neg A$ is a contradiction)

In a similar vein, [Russell's Paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%2527s_paradox). The problem here is that you need some basic set theory, so this is more for advanced high school students.

The first beautiful proof I saw in high school (it was beautiful at the time, but now seems too trivial) was the fact that for a geometric series $a, ax, ax^2, \dots$ the sum of the first $n$ terms is $a \cdot \frac{1-x^n}{1-x}$. I thought this was cool because of all the cancellation that seems to come out of nowhere. The treatment [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) is nice.

Comment: I haven't taught high school in many years, and I never tried teaching these things there.  My impression however, is that the Halting Problem, although the proof is indeed elementary, is conceptually very sophisticated.  I think it's one of those things that people have to mull over for years to really get an appreciation for.  Maybe some teachers, with some classes, could do this.  But I bet that most high school students might be able to follow "every line of the proof", but they'd see it as just a trick.  I'd love to be proved wrong.  Maybe the same is true for Russell's paradox.

Answer (score 13):

One of the keys to making a proof accessible to high school students (or just non-mathematicians) is to make the answer relevant. This gives a dual responsibility, to ensure that the theorem is motivated and that the proof is accessible. The proof of the infinity of the primes has been mentioned already and is a fantastic example. You can lead students in to it using the (almost trivial) proof that there is no largest integer.

Another example is the classification of the regular polyhedra. With good students and models you can even lead them to the proof there there are at most 6 regular polytopes in 4d (actually showing they all exist is a little harder).

Keeping with polyhedra, the Euler characteristic is also powerful. Start with balloons and get the students to draw lines freely so you get a tiling. Then get them to count faces, vertices and edges. David Eppstein collected 19 proofs to choose from, several of which would be perfect for non-mathematicians: http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/junkyard/euler/

As a final example (and to show that it does not have to be deep mathematics to motivate) you can consider the question of blocking a square on a chess board and filling the remainder with tromioes. It starts with a puzzle, you can get people to play with, and leads to a lovely induction proof: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Games/TriggTromino.shtml

Actually polyominoes are a fantastic source of many other fun, non-trivial but accessible proofs.

Answer (score 13):

This topological proof of the fundamental theorem of algebra is accessible to high school students, particularly those at the precalculus level.

[image] [<sup>(source)</sup>](http://thenerdiestshirts.com/images/zoom/math-shirt-fta-yellow.gif)

There are two major problems with this. First, while the winding number is intuitive, it takes effort to define it rigorously. Second, you also want to establish the basic property that the winding number doesn't change as you deform a curve without going over the origin, which again is difficult to establish rigorously without topology. Without these details, you might call this a hand-waving argument instead of a proof. It's good to give references to where these results will be established rigorously, and to give arguments for other results which are more complete.

Nevertheless, I like presenting this proof for several reasons. I think it's beautiful. Geometrically, what $x\mapsto x^n$ does to the complex plane is easy to understand, but many students have little intuition about what this map does, only what polynomials look like on the real line. So, this argument doesn't just say that the statement is true, it is illuminating. The fundamental theorem of algebra is also a result students encountered in algebra, but they usually don't know why it's called a theorem. This is also an opportunity to talk a little about what is studied in more advanced areas of mathematics. It can lead into discussions of topology or the difficulty solving polynomials by radicals.

Comment: @Douglas: I ask this question out of ignorance; it's not a criticism. How many high-school students have been introduced to the complex plane sufficiently to *grok* this?

Comment: @Joseph O'Rourke: I don't think many high school students are really comfortable with the complex plane, but I think you can develop key facts within this argument, particularly for precalculus students who are used to problems like calculating $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x^4+1}{x-3}$. 

Answer (score 12):

I've been collecting simple, often one-step, proofs.

http://www.cut-the-knot.org/proofs/index.shtml

Some I judge beautiful - these are listed separately.

Answer (score 11):

I recommend Kelly's proof of the Sylvester-Gallai theorem (the original proof of Gallai was about 30 pages long, this one takes a few lines). The theorem and the proof can be read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester-Gallai_theorem).

Comment: I don’t understand the proof as given in the Wikipedia article. The picture is very suggestive, but as far as I can see, there is actually nothing in the proof that prevents the intersection of $m$ and $l$ to fall on the other side of the perpendicular (e.g., it may be $A$), in which case it can easily happen that the distance of $B$ from $m$ is larger than the distance of $P$ from $l$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Emil: There are at least 3 points on $l$, at least two on one side of the perpendicular. Call the closer of these two $B$ and the farther of these two $C$. Now let $m$ denote the line $PC$, then the pair $(B,m)$ has a smaller distance than $(P,l)$. Contradiction.

Comment: This brings up a memory. It was at McGill. Moser had just received an award from the CMS. I asked him about his work and somehow this problem and the related problem of finding the best lower bound for the number of "ordinary lines" came up. The funny thing is that Moser wanted to write on the back of the letter he had just received from CMS! If I remember well, a woman told him not do that (it may have been his wife).

Answer (score 11):

Minkowski's Theorem (every convex region in the plane of area greater than 4 that's symmetric about the origin contains a lattice point other than (0,0)) is not at all obvious (are you sure you can't squeeze a sufficiently large "blob of irrational slope" in there?) but has a beautiful, simple, and surprising geometric proof.

Comment: Do you want to give a hint about the proof?

Comment: Draw the region $R$ in the plane. Cut the plane into 2x2 squares by cutting along the lines $x=2i$ and $y=2j$ for all integers $i,j$; each square contains some part of $R$ (possible none.) Stack the squares on top of each other. Since $R$ has area greater than 4, there exist two squares whose parts of $R$ overlap. Write down what this means algebraically, apply symmetry and convexity, and construct the nontrivial lattice point.

Answer (score 11):

Im in high school and i loved the proof of the fermat-toriccelli point of a triangle.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't think I saw that one in high school!

Answer (score 10):

For someone in high school, I think it's good to prove that the sum of the interior angles of a triangle is $\pi$ if they don't know why.  Personally, I was never shown why this fact is true, and I feel that it's generally a bad idea to not know why something in math is true, especially when the answer is pretty.  My favorite proof is to think about how the normal vector changes as you walk around the triangle -- it's nice because it generalizes to other shapes (which may not even be polygons).

Comment: Relatedly, the Pythagorean theorem, and its connection to the parallel postulate, is really worthwhile.

Answer (score 8):

1) Many elementary binomial identities or identities with Fibonacci numbers have beautiful proofs. 
Let me only mention the matrix representation of Fibonacci numbers whose determinant gives Cassini's identity.

2) Another elementary problem is the following: Is it possible to cover a checkerboard  from which one white and one black square have been removed with dominoes?
To show that this is possible run through the board in a cyclical way.  Observe that on this path between a white and a black square are an even number of squares.
Since I don't know how to make figures I indicate such a path for a 4x4-board:  ((1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,4),(2,3),(2,2),(3,2),(3,3),(3,4),(4,4),(4,3),(4,2),(4,1),(3,1),(2,1)).

Comment: I would also add the (checkerboard) proof that if you remove opposite corners from the 8x8 board, the resulting figure can't be tiled with dominoes; if presented without the board coloration it's not immediately obvious, and its proof provides a wonderful a-ha moment that should be easily accessible for high school students (if not earlier).  These (along with the various graph-theory problems) also have the advantage of showing students that mathematics is about more than just numbers.

Comment: Steven, +1, but even when you present with the board coloration it's not obvious... until they see it! And then it *is* suddenly obvious. 

Answer (score 8):

You should certainly look at the two books by Ross Honsberger, "Mathematical Gems I" and "Mathematical Gems II". A favourite example of mine the proof due to Conway that there are configurations of checkers below the half plane on an infinite board that allow you to move a checker 4 rows into the upper half plane, but not five rows.

The negative result is an ingenious argument using nothing more than the quadratic formula, but provides a great example of to apply mathematics in unexpected contexts.

Comment: The way I remember the negative result was that you associate a weight to the checkers so that jumping and removing keeps the weight the same, and the infinite sum $\sum (2n+1) \Phi^{-n}$ for the weight of the lower half plane converges and can be calculated. That last calculation seems too complicated for middle school students who aren't comfortable with $\sum 1/2^n$ or $\Phi$. The positive result is a simple exercise requiring no background. Since the whole question is very abstract I don't think this is an unexpected application of mathematics.

Comment: I was under the impression that 5 rows up is attainable if you use all of the spaces in the lower half plane (assuming a suitable notion of doing infinitely many hopping moves).

Comment: Well, $5$ is not attainable if you allow infinite well-ordered sequences of moves and take position-wise limits at the limit points. 

Comment: I don't understand how infinitely many moves can help. If a checker arrives at a certain spot then it did so in finitely many moves. Of course one could use an ultrafilter and say a checker arrives at a spot if it lands there ultrafilter often, but I don't see how this would be much use either

The infinite dimensions of the board simply allow all finite configurations.

Comment: In answer to Douglas Zare, the argument I remember did involve summing a geometric series of number that are the roots of a quadratic polynomial. You are right that this is probably too advanced for most high school students, bug I ythink it could be taught to bright students of the type that this hypothetical course would be geared towards.

Answer (score 8):

I suggest Euler's polyeder formula with application to the Platonic solids. 
One first observes that instead of  polyeders one can consider graphs in the plane, counting the unbounded region as a face. One observes next that one can just as well allow the edges to be pieces of curves. Then one observes that the formula $F - E + V = 2$ is preserved if one edge or one vertex is added, thus the formula is proved by induction. Then use the formula to prove that there are no regular polyeders except the five Platonic solids as follows: faces can only be triangles, squares or pentagons, edges are always common to exactly two faces, and for the number of faces that meet in a vertex there are a number of possibilities that one checks. For each case, $E$ and $V$ can be expressed in terms of $F$, and the formula gives the possible values of $F$.

Comment: See Edmund Hariss's earlier, similar suggestion.

Comment: Per @JosephO'Rourke's suggestion, [@‍EdmundHarriss's earlier, similar suggestion](https://mathoverflow.net/a/74878/2383).

Answer (score 7):

The formula $1 + 2 + \cdots + n = n(n+1)/2$ can be proved on middle school level: Assume first $n$ is even. Then there are $n/2$ pairs $(1,n), (2,n-1), \ldots, (n/2,n/2+1)$ those sum is always $n+1.$ Thus the overall sum is $n/2\cdot(n+1).$ The case when $n$ is odd can be treated in the same manner.

Comment: And do you think this proof is really beautiful (as opposed to neat, cool, or something like that)?


Comment: Actually this proof would be more approriate for primary school (age 10 or so). Smarter kids (like Gauss) figure it out themselves.

Comment: A nicer proof is double counting. There are $n+1$ people at a party, and everyone should shake hands with everyone else. How many handshakes all in all? 1st way: line the guests up in a row, everyone shakes the hand of those to their right. Sum up the total amount of handshakes. 2nd way: there are clearly $(n+1)\cdot n$ *ordered* pairs of guests, so there must be $(n+1)\cdot n/2$ unordered pairs of guests.

Comment: I prefer the "visual proof" because you don't have to reason, you just "see" it: put 1 little square in the first raw, two in the second,... n in the last raw, and you've obtained a figure of which you can easily compute the area as: (AreaOfBigSquare-AreaOfSquaresOnTheDiagonal)/2+ AreaOfSquaresOnTheDiagonal=$(n^2-n)/2+n=n(n+1)/2$. Of course to pass from $(n^2-n)/2+n$ to $n(n+1)/2$ the kid must have learned some "algebra".

Comment: No, the *best* proof is the visual one where you draw a triangle with 1, 2, ..., n circles in each row, and another row below the last with n + 1 circles.  Anything in the smaller triangle can be specified by two "coordinates" in the last row, obtained by dropping down parallel to the sides.  Thus, $\binom{n + 1}{2}$ using the *definition* of "n + 1 choose 2"; to get a formula for that number you could use the argument in Dan's comment.  This one is nice because it is both visual and a bijective proof, rather than computational.

Comment: How about this: write the numbers from $1$ to $n$ in row, then write them again in a row below, but backwards.  Add up the columns, to get $n+1$ each time, so $n(n+1)$ in total, because there are $n$ columns.  Divide by $2$.

Answer (score 7):

i suggest the proof archimedes wanted on his tombstone and its relatives.  i.e. since two solids with the same horizontal slice area at every height have the same volume,  hence by pythagoras, the volume of a cylinder equals the sum of the volumes of an inscribed cone and an inscribed solid hemisphere.

to generalize this, the volume generated by revolving a solid hemisphere around a planar axis in 4 space equal that generated by revolving a cylinder minus that generated by revolving a cone.  Using the fact that the center of gravity of a cone is 1/4 the way up from the base, one obtains the volume of a 4-sphere, as pi^2/2 R^4.

a generalization of the first computation is that of the volume of a bicylinder (intersection of two perpendicular cylinders), since it is the difference of the volumes of a cube containing the bicylinder and a square based double pyramid also inscribed in the cube.

I find these beautiful, but of course that is subjective.

I also like euclid's argument for pythagoras, and for constructing a regular pentagon, but they are hard to reproduce here briefly.

Answer (score 7):

Here is one that I like and used it for different purposes, e.g. introduction to proofs, algebraic thinking, beauty, and so one. Shuffle a deck of cards. Divide it into two halves. Magic: The number of the red cards in one of the halves is exactly equal to the number of black cards in the other half. It has a simple algebraic proof. However, The bigger magic is yet to come.

Theorem: Vertically opposite angles are equal.

Bigger Magic: The two theorems/proofs are essentially the same!

Answer (score 6):

There is a very elegant proof that there exists no continuous injection from the plane into the real line. The proof can basically be given by drawing a picture on the blackboard.

Suppose there is such an injection $f$. Let $x$ and $y$ be distinct points in the plane and let $g_1$ and $g_2$ be paths from $x$ to $y$ such that $g_1(r_1)\neq g_2(r_2)$ for $r_1,r_2\in (0,1)$. Now this implies that $f\circ g_1((0,1))\cap f\circ g_2((0,1))=\emptyset$, contradicting the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: But what is the point of proving a theorem as intuitively obvious as this in the eyes of a high-schooler?

Comment: Also, continuous functions in more than 1 dimension are usually not defined in high school...

Comment: In fact, one might not even explicitly define 'continuous' at all in high school, as everything they're going to work with (polynomials, exp, log) is continuous anyway.

Answer (score 6):

[Morley's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morley%27s_trisector_theorem).

Wikipedia's proof is completely elementary and only involves trigonometric identities and euclidean plane geometry.

There is also a [proof](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=PMIHES_1998__S88__43_0) by Alain Connes, based on affine geometry techniques. Of course it is a bit more technical, but again it involves math that doesn't go much beyond the high school level, and could be appreciated by the most gifted students

Comment: Thanks.  Actually this example was given by Rota in a famous paper about the phenomenology of mathematical beauty as an example of a theorem that is surprising but not beautiful (in response to Hardy's claim that beauty arises from a feeling of surprise.)  Of course, it is open to debate...

Thanks for the Connes reference, I didn't know about that.

Comment: See also Conway's proof (linked at the Wikipedia article). 

Comment: @Manya: Well, I guess it's a matter of taste. Personally, I *do* find this theorem beautiful. Thank you for the remark

Comment: But the question was asking for a beautiful proof, not a beautiful theorem. 

Comment: I guess that's a matter of taste, too. Anyway, Connes' proof is not so bad :-)

Comment: P.S. (@ eucklid) Good point. Rota actually claimed that neither the theorem nor any of the proofs of it (thus far?) are beautiful.

Comment: I was going to suggest this example too, particularly Connes' proof, which is just a calculation inside the group of affine transformations in the plane.

Answer (score 6):

Those are pretty nice, and can be done at a fairly low level (say, from 12 years old onwards) :

- The proof of the formula "half base times height" for the area of a triangle, by first considering a right triangle and completing a rectangle, then considering an arbitrary triangle and breaking it in two along an height (two cases : inside(+) or outside(-)) : it is a nice example of how mathematicians treat the general case by reduction to particular cases ;
- Euclid's proof of the pythagorean theorem using the previous formula, as in [this animation](http://www.mathkang.org/swf/pythagore.html).

Comment: Good example:I remember being excited by this when I understood why this worked at school. 

Answer (score 6):

Using Euler's formula ($F-E+V=2$, as mentioned earlier), it can be proved that the graphs $K_5$ and $K_{3,3}$ are not planar. I think these proof and also the proof of Euler's formula are simple enough to be understood by an interested high school student.

Answer (score 5):

In the general game "Poset Chomp" the first player always has a winning strategy. The proof is a one-line strategy stealing argument, hence nonconstructive. In fact, a winning strategy is unknown in most cases, which makes the result interesting and mysterious. For a good quick account see [here](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/games/chomp.html).

Comment: I don't expect middle school students to be familiar with posets or abstract games. 

Comment: @Douglas: Read carefully the link. Special cases of "Poset Chomp", e.g. the one where the players choose divisors of a given integer do not need any knowledge of posets or abstract games: it can be played by a 10-year old.

Comment: @Douglas: Quote from the link: "Schuh published in 1952 his "game of divisors" ([1]). Here the partially ordered set is that of all divisors of a fixed number N, with x below y when y|x."

Comment: @Douglas: Another quote from the link: "David Gale reinvented this game ([2,2a]). His version is that of the m-by-n chocolate bar, where square (0,0) (say, the lower left-hand corner) is poisoned, and players take turns eating a "chomp": a square (a,b) together with all squares to the left and/or above it."

Comment: @GH: I'm aware of the history of chomp and of simple posets and the strategy-stealing argument. Have you worked with middle school students who were not selected to be competitors in a math competition? What percentage do you think will understand and be impressed by a nonconstructive existence result about an abstract game they have not seen before? When I tell members of the general public about mathematics, I try to relate it to concrete objects and situations I think they know beforehand.

Comment: @Douglas: I admit I have never worked with middle school students who were not selected to be competitors in a math competition. Still I think this proof can teach so much about mathematics in so little time.

Answer (score 5):

I like the lovely theorem in 19th century Euclidean Geometry as follows.

Let ABC be a triangle. let D,E,F be points on BC,CA,AB respectively. Then the circumcircles of AFE, BDF, CDE meet at a point.

I like this because the proof  uses the property of the angles of cyclic quadrilaterals, and its converse.  Also if one wants to convince students of the necessity of proof, then one should start with a result which is surprising.

It is a good thing that this situation can we worked on for more implications. Let P,Q,R be the centres of the three circles just given. Then the triangle PQR is similar to the triangle ABC.

For all these reasons I think it is a pity that some of Euclidean Geometry is not in University courses, or often school courses, in order to acquaint students with something important  in our mathematical heritage. Should a student get a degree in maths without knowing why the angle in a semicircle is a right angle?

Answer (score 5):

**Fermat's Little Theorem:**  If $p$ is prime and does not divide $a$, then $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 (\mbox{mod } p)$.

**Proof:** List the multiples of $a$ up to $a(p-1)$:

$$ a, a2, a3, \dots , a(p-1).$$

For any $r$ and $s$ with, $ra \equiv sa (\mbox{mod } p)$, we have $r \equiv s (\mbox{mod } p)$, so that the list above contains $p-1$ many distinct numbers.

Thus, the list above is some ordering of the list $1, 2, 3, \dots p-1$ modulo $p$.  This gives us
$$  a\cdot a2 \cdot a3 \cdot \cdots a(p-1) \equiv (p-1)! (\mbox{mod } p) $$

Finally we see

$$ a^{p-1} \equiv 1 (\mbox{mod } p).  $$

Answer (score 4):

Why not some elementary theorems of Euclidan geometry?  As I recall, the more general and fundamental theorems were just taken as given in my schooling, but I think many of them can be given accessible and beautiful proofs.  Here are some good ones:

1) The Pythagorean theorem. (many lovely proofs)

2) Parallelograms having congruent bases and heights have the same area.  (Euclid's proof is pretty.)

3) Use 2 to derive that similar triangles have corresponding sides in common proportion.

4) Two distinct circles have at most 2 points of intersection.

5) Prove the formula for volume of a pyramid without using calculus.

Comment: What I absolutely dislike about 4) is how it cements the common misconception that mathematics is about giving painstakingly difficult proofs to intuitively obvious statements. Part 3) is only slightly better in this aspect. The rest are pretty good.

Comment: The arguments are not so painful.  #4 merely involves some observations relating the center of a circle, isoceles triangles, and the fact that two distinct lines intersect at most once.  In any case I disagree with the sentiment.  Part of the mathematical way of thinking is resisting the urge to accept things just because they seem obvious at first, and always demand that your knowledge but put on a firmer footing.  I believe this is the essential "life lesson" students should take from mathematics.  Sadly it is not being imparted in today's secondary schools much.

Comment: I disagree. In school, mathematical proofs are like castles built on sand - not only do most students never realize what they are for, but they often tend to be sloppy right up to flawed (not "flawed" in the sense of "informal", but flawed in the sense of arguments that wouldn't be accepted as a correct proof even in a published paper), and the idea that proofs can be interesting is totally missing (at best they are considered a necessary evil by students and teachers alike). Adding to this a "revelation" that mathematicians prove trivial things in complicated (for students, at least) ...

Comment: ... ways doesn't help. In reality, mathematics is maybe 1% about proving things that are intuitively obvious (even topology), and 99% about proving things that are either surprising or seem to be useful in proving surprising things. Skepticism is a good life lesson, but it is better taught by providing examples of *false* intuitively obvious assertions with counterexamples than by providing examples of *correct* intuitively obvious assertions with their seemingly redundant proofs.

Comment: Having taught the first 4 or 5 books of Euclid to bright 8-10 year olds, I agree with mbsq, but it doesn't sound as if darj is to be easily convinced.  And I also agree that one of the interesting things about proofs in math is clarifying just why one thinks something is obvious, and sometimes finding out that one has been missing a lot of subtlety.  When showing that a parallelogram can be transformed into a rectangle of same area, how many of us have been guilty of always drawing the parallelogram with one upper vertex lying directly over the base?  Euclid is more thorough.

Answer (score 4):

After two concrete answers, let me give a third, rambling answer:

A few years ago I decided to completely quit elementary geometry because it was still taking up half of my time even as I was already studying in university. Given that I have been doing it for most of my schoolyears, this should give an impression of how much there is to be done there - and all of it is comprehensible to a good school student.

I will not go into details, but this is a community wiki post ;)

First, there are so many lines in a triangle meeting at one point that one can reasonably ask whether there exist three symmetrically-defined lines *not* doing so. (There are, of course: e. g., the reflections of the medians in the corresponding altitudes.) This does not change the fact that each concurrence theorem is still a nontrivial result asking for a proof. Some of the basic cases can be handled with Ceva; harder results can take a dozen of pages to prove. The points where these lines concur often have several equivalent characterizations and collinearity properties (like the Euler line); this led Clark Kimberling to make an [encyclopedia of such points](http://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETC.html) similar to [Sloane's On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org/). An easy example is the concurrence of the lines $AX$, $BY$, $CZ$, where $X$, $Y$, $Z$ are the points where the incircle of triangle $ABC$ touches the sides $BC$, $CA$, $AB$. (The point where they concur is known as the Gergonne point of triangle $ABC$, known as $X_7$ in [1](http://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETC.html).) A not-so-easy example: If $O$ is the circumcenter of triangle $ABC$, then the lines connecting $A$, $B$, $C$ with the circumcenters of triangles $OBC$, $OCA$, $OAB$ concur. (This is the Kosnita point, aka $X_{54}$ in [1](http://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETC.html).) Then there are more complicated things, like: Consider the points where the excircle of triangle $ABC$ opposite to $A$ touches the extended sides $AB$ and $AC$. Let $M_a$ be the midpoint between these two points. Let $M_b$ and $M_c$ be defined similarly. Let the incircle of triangle $ABC$ touches the sides $BC$, $CA$, $AB$ at $X$, $Y$, $Z$. Then, the lines $M_aX$, $M_bY$, $M_cZ$ concur (at a point which is $X_{1122}$ in [1](http://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETC.html); this is something I have discovered back in schooltime when playing around with dynamic geometry software).

Of course, concurrent lines aren't even half of the fun. There are theorems like Feuerbach's, stating that the nine-point circle touches the incircle and the excircles. This is some centuries old. Here is one found in 2000 by Floor van Lamoen: The medians of a triangle subdivide it in six little triangles (of equal area, by the way); the circumcenters of these triangles lie on one circle! Or here is another tangency property: If the incircle of triangle $ABC$ touches the side $BC$ at a point $X$, then the incircles of triangles $ABX$ and $ACX$ touch each other.

All theorems I mentioned can be proven in a synthetic way, i. e., using merely the part of elementary geometry studied in school, without coordinates or overly long computations. ("Overly long" is subjective and I am well aware of this.) This makes the field completely accessible to students. This is not to say that advanced mathematics doesn't shed some new light on it. For instance, one could try generalizing the above-mentioned Kosnita point by looking for all the points $P$ such that the lines connecting $A$, $B$, $C$ with the circumcenters of triangles $PBC$, $PCA$, $PAB$ concur. The answer turns out to be that the set of such points $P$ is a cubic curve known as [the Neuberg cubic](http://bernard.gibert.pagesperso-orange.fr/Exemples/k001.html) of triangle $ABC$. The sheer amount of interesting points on it allow for some neat applications of the group law on cubics to elementary geometric theorems.

I have been rather sparse with sources, as I haven't been keeping track of them for years. Some can be found on [my links page](http://mit.edu/~darij/www/Links.html), but it has not been updated since 2008 or so. Nowadays [Jean-Louis Ayme's blog](http://jl.ayme.pagesperso-orange.fr/contenu.html) is the best place to find more synthetic proofs than one could ever read. There are also some [good books](http://mit.edu/~darij/www/faq.html#books). (Sorry for linking to my page this often; it is the one place on the internet I am most familiar with...)

Answer (score 4):

I actually think that [Hilbert's Third problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_third_problem) is one of the explainable for school guys. It's even more cool that it exists in such a famous list close to the problems that are so tempting and not yet solved.
The question is: can one cut the cube in some polyhedral pieces, reglue them and get a regular tetrahedron? The answer is no and the theorem was proved by Dehn using so-called Dehn invariant. It uses some algebra and number theory but can be understood by high-school level guys. The time you need to explain this is 3-4 hours, so maybe it could be a little and nice course.
See, for example, Lectures on Discrete and Polyhedral Geometry by I. Pak

Answer (score 4):

If each brick in a tiling of a rectangle has an integer side, the rectangle does too. This has various generalizations and lots of proofs, some very accessible, like number 7 here:

https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Wagon601-617.pdf

Answer (score 4):

The most success I have ever had teaching proofs at secondary school level is with the Peaucellier–Lipkin linkage. The proof relies on nothing more than basic geometry, namely similar triangles, but the outcome really is amazing. I found it reading Tom Körner's book called Fourier Analysis.

You can get the proof from Wikipedia, and there are some videos around if you google for them. Körner goes into the history of the problem, he believes Tchebychev was of the opinion that the problem couldn't be solved! And there is a great quote attributed to Kelvin, which I'll leave you with. When Sylvester showed a working model to him...

'[he] nursed it as if it had been his own child, and when a motion was made to relieve him of it, replied "No! I have not had nearly enough of it - it is the most beautiful thing I have ever seen in my life."'

Comment: Links:  [the Peaucellier–Lipkin linkage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peaucellier–Lipkin_linkage); [Körner - Fourier analysis](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/fourier-analysis/132E61BE81FD1190F35F9631089CA132); [Körner's discussion of the PL linkage on Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=OcZ5iKsGrmoC&vq=Peaucellier&pg=PA198).

Answer (score 3):

Sperner's lemma (in dimension 2 to keep it visual). The proof in Francis Su's [Monthly paper](http://mathdl.maa.org/mathDL/22/?pa=content&sa=viewDocument&nodeId=2706), *Rental harmony: Sperner's lemma in fair division* is especially easy to visualize. Theris a non-empty content, you can have students ponder the role of the hypotheses. And fair division applications allow to motivate it via concrete applications.

Comment: There's a bizarre application of Sperner's lemma that's hard for high-school students (but I did give a talk to a group of them about it):
one can't dissect a square into an odd number of non-overlapping triangles, all of the same area.

Comment: @paulMonsky, do you know a reference where this is written up?

Comment: @LSpice   Google "Monsky's Theorem" and you'll find many write-ups.

Answer (score 3):

This is maybe ambitious, for the details are obviously not completely accessible to the high school level; but the beauty of the ideas is, and this video is really a superb example of divulgation. [Smale's theorem on the eversion of the 2-sphere and Thurston's construction](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BVVfs4zKrgk&feature=player_embedded).

Comment: Yeah, maybe ambitious, but is was a very nice film. I had seen other animations of sphere eversion before, but this was definitely the most pedagogical.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of good suggestions in this feed, but here are a few problems that let you introduce modular arithmetic.

First, one can easily prove that an integer mod 9 is equal to the sum of its digits mod 9.

Second, you can prove Fermat's little theorem k^p mod p = k where p is prime.

I suppose that even (a+b) mod n = (a mod n + b mod n) mod n is kind of neat too.

You can prove that the calendar repeats itself every 28 years.

Comment: Under certain faulty assumptions, calendar periodicity holds.  Calendar reform will likely perturb the current arrangement into something nonperiodic, to reflect astronomical observation.  So talk about an idealized calendar, or something other than "the" calendar.  Gerhard "What Time Is It Anyway?" Paseman, 2012.11.05

Answer (score 3):

I love the incredibly clever proof of Sylvester’s theorem ([https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester–Gallai_theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%E2%80%93Gallai_theorem)) by Kelly. It is described nicely in the wiki page.

Answer (score 2):

I think the fundamentals of the theory of quadratic residues modulo a prime qualify.

It is easy to explain what residue classes modulo a prime $p$ are, and to formulate statements of this kind:

**1.** The product of two quadratic residues modulo $p$ is a quadratic residue.

**2.** The product of a quadratic residue and a quadratic nonresidue modulo $p$ is a quadratic nonresidue.

**3.** The product of two quadratic nonresidues modulo $p$ is a quadratic residue.

(Note that I am not counting $0$ as a quadratic residue, nor as a quadratic nonresidue.)

Now **1** and **2** are very easy to show. **3** is not. What do we do?

First, it is easy to see that every quadratic residue is the square of exactly $2$ distinct residues modulo $p$. Thus there are exactly $\frac{p-1}{2}$ quadratic residues modulo $p$. Hence, there are exactly $\left(p-1\right)-\frac{p-1}{2}=\frac{p-1}{2}$ quadratic nonresidues modulo $p$. Now let $a$ and $b$ be two quadratic nonresidues. If $ab$ is a quadratic nonresidue, then there are at least $\frac{p-1}{2}+1$ different residues $x$ modulo $p$ for which $ax$ is a quadratic nonresidue (namely, each of the $\frac{p-1}{2}$ quadratic residues qualifies as such $x$ (by statement **2**), but the quadratic nonresidue $b$ also qualifies), which leads to at least $\frac{p-1}{2}+1$ different quadratic nonresidues (since distinct $x$'es lead to distinct $ax$'es), contradicting the fact that there are only $\frac{p-1}{2}$ quadratic nonresidues modulo $p$. Thus, $ab$ must be a quadratic residue, and **3** is proven.

This indirect argument is, I believe, understandable to high school students. The only two theorems we used are:

**A.** Every quadratic residue is the square of exactly $2$ distinct residues modulo $p$.

**B.** If $a$ is a nonzero residue modulo $p$, then distinct $x$'es lead to distinct $ax$'es.

Both of these theorems can be derived from the following well-known fact:

**F.** If a prime divides a product of two integers, then it divides one of these two integers.

*Proof of **A**:* Assume that $a^2 \equiv b^2 \equiv c^2 \mod p$ for three integers $a$, $b$, $c$ pairwise incongruent modulo $p$. Then, $a^2 \equiv b^2 \mod p$ rewrites as $p\mid \left(a+b\right)\left(a-b\right)$. Hence (by fact **F**), at least one of $a+b$ and $a-b$ is divisible by $p$. Since $a$ and $b$ are incongruent modulo $p$, this can only mean that $a+b$ is divisible by $p$. Similarly, $b+c$ and $c+a$ are divisible by $p$. But therefore $2a=\left(a+b\right)+\left(c+a\right)-\left(b+c\right)$ must also be divisible by $p$. Since $p$ cannot be $2$ (as there are no three integers pairwise incongruent modulo $2$), this yields that $a$ is divisible by $p$. Similarly, $b$ and $c$ are divisible by $p$, which contradicts with their being incongruent. This proves **A**.

The proof of **B** is much simpler. The fact **F** is also used in one possible proof of statement **2**. (However we can also prove **2** using **1** by the same trick as we used to prove **3** using **2**.)

We have thus used the fact **F** a lot of times, but other than that, we didn't apply anything nontrivial - not even the theorem that a nonzero polynomial over a field cannot have more roots than its degree (this fact is often used in university-level treatises of quadratic residues).

The hard part is to tell students what is interesting about quadratic residues. Maybe cryptography?

Comment: Concerning the very last phrase - I believe quadratic residues may be well motivated by themselves. Once there is an understanding that it is important to know which numbers possess square roots (gradually backwards - reals, rationals, integers), it is quite natural to ask this modulo some $n$.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I can't guarantee that I can make you happy, but atleast guess that I can. A simple problem: **Determine the set of all points lying in the plane of a triangle ABC (say P), for which (PA)^2+(PB)^2+(PC)^2 is minimum.** We all know that this set is the singleton set: {Centroid G of ABC}. Unfortunately, a previous knowledge of the answer makes it easy to prove the assertion, but more unfortunately, even after stating:"*We will show that the centroid is the only such point*", most books give a long, boring proof, involving non-trivial and non-motivating constructions and lengthy calculations. Right, I'm going to give a what-I-think beautiful proof, which is due to me! I solved it while preparing for the Indian National Mathematical Olympiad last year. Just join P with C1,A1,B1, the midpoints of AB,BC,CA,resp and form the triangle A1B1C1. Note that A1B1C1 is the image of ABC under a homothety of factor -0.5 about their common centroid. Next, applying the Apollonius' theorem on the 3 triangles APB, BPC & CPA and adding the 3 relations, note that PA^2+PB^2+PC^2 is minimum, if  and only if PA1^2+PB1^2+PC1^2 is minimum. That the set above is singleton, is immediate from the extremal principle applied to 2 possible points having the same property and showing that their midpoint has the sum of squares less than them. Now, let P'
be the image of P under the homothety -0.5. Then, by properties of homothety, P' and P both have minimum sum-of-squares with respect to A1B1C1. But the set is singleton, so P=P'. However, the only point that remains invariant under a homothety is the centre, which in this case, is the centroid!!:) Right, whenever one sees the sum-of-squares form one guesses to apply Apollonius' theorem and this proof doesn't even require a pre-knowledge of the answer! Please tell me if you've enjoyed it or not!

Comment: If $P$ is the minimizer and $Q$ in any other point, then $QA^2=PA^2+2<PA,V>+V^2$, where $V=QP$, by the bilinearity of the inner product.  Therefore, we must have $<PA+PB+PC,V>\geq 0$ for any vector $V$, which means $PA+PB+PC=0$. This argument, btw, has nothing to do with triangles, dimension 2, etc. I feel that teaching the high school students any other proof is a missed opportunity of such a great magnitude that it is tantamount to child abuse.

Answer (score 2):

Well I personally liked the **[Euler's Theorem](http://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/10/15/a-theorem-by-euler-on-partitions/)** when I first saw, and I feel one can easily understand it at the High-School level.

There is a Youtube video with William Dunham's lecture on Euler which contains this theorem at 32:30 : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fEWj93XjON0

Answer (score 2):

Quite elementary and quite beautiful: There exist two (infinitely many) irrational numbers $a,b$ such that $a^b$ is rational; and the usual proof with $\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}$. (Maybe starting with the proof of $\sqrt{p}$ being irrational for any prime $p>0$.)

Comment: Not sure what you have in mind, but to my taste the business about $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$ (the elementary nonconstructive proof) is not as nice as the observation that if $a = \sqrt{2}, b = 2\log 3/\log 2$, then $a^b = 3$, where $a, b$ are irrational essentially by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic (unique prime factorization). This can be extended ad infinitum, and is moreover perfectly constructive.

Answer (score 2):

I would put on such a list the proof of the *Cauchy-Schwarz inequality* directly from the axioms of an inner product using the discriminant criterion for the classification of the roots of a second-order polynomial with real coefficients. The latter is something all high school students either learn or already know, but it is a common target in those jokes about the parts of school math that most people find "useless"... The axioms for an inner product themselves are easy to motivate from $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Let me recall the proof here because it is that simple... Let $V$ be a (real) vector space with an inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$, and let $\vec{x},\vec{y}\in V$. We want to prove that $$\langle\vec{x},\vec{y}\rangle^2\leq\langle\vec{x},\vec{x}\rangle\langle\vec{y},\vec{y}\rangle\ ,$$ with equality iff $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$ are collinear (i.e. linearly dependent). Since $\langle\vec{y},\vec{y}\rangle=0$ iff $\vec{y}=\vec{0}$ (*nondegeneracy* axiom) and in that case $\langle\vec{x},\vec{y}\rangle=0$ for all $\vec{x}\in V$ (due to the *bilinearity* axiom) the Cauchy -Schwarz inequality holds (with equality) if $\vec{y}=\vec{0}$, so there is no loss of generality if we assume $\vec{y}\neq\vec{0}$. In that case, define for $t\in\mathbb{R}$ $$P(t)=\langle\vec{x}+t\vec{y},\vec{x}+t\vec{y}\rangle=\langle\vec{y},\vec{y}\rangle t^2+2\langle\vec{x},\vec{y}\rangle t+\langle\vec{x},\vec{x}\rangle\ ,$$
where the last equality follows from the *bilinearity* and *symmetry* axioms. Now, due to the *positive definiteness* axiom (of which, let us recall, the nondegeneracy axiom is a consequence), we must have $P(t)\geq 0$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$. Recall now that the roots $t_\pm$ of a second-order polynomial $Q(t)=at^2+bt+c$ with real coefficients $a,b,c$ ($a\neq 0$) are given by the discriminant formula $$t_\pm=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}\ ,$$ where the *discriminant* $\Delta$ of $Q(t)$ is given by $\Delta=b^2-4ac$. In the case that $Q(t)=P(t)$, one has that $\Delta=4(\langle\vec{x},\vec{y}\rangle^2-\langle\vec{x},\vec{x}\rangle\langle\vec{y},\vec{y}\rangle)$. Since $P(t)\geq 0$ for all $t$, this implies that $P(t)$ has *at most one* real root, which is only possible if $\Delta\leq 0$, whence the above inequality follows. The equality case happens if and only if $t=t_+=t_-$ is the only real root of $P(t)$ - for such a $t$, the nondegeneracy axiom implies that $\vec{x}=-t\vec{y}$, that is, $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$ are collinear.

The above proof is completely general (works also for complex vector spaces and in infinite dimensions) and the actual result lies at the basis of Euclidean geometry, for one can get from it all the properties of the Euclidean distance and it also guarantees that the definition of the (Euclidean) angle between vectors makes sense through the cosine rule $$\angle(\vec{x},\vec{y})=\arccos\left(\frac{\langle\vec{x},\vec{y}\rangle}{\sqrt{\langle\vec{x},\vec{x}\rangle\langle\vec{y},\vec{y}\rangle}}\right)\ ,$$ so one can also use the latter to tell the students: "Do you see? The discriminant formula plays a role whenever you are doing any kind of Euclidean geometry..." In other words, it displays a deep connection about two seemingly completely different areas of mathematics (geometry and algebra).

Answer (score 1):

Figuring out the Lagrange interpolation polynomial was a pretty awesome moment for me as a high school nerd.

I was amazed a while later that you can simulate a Turing machine with just two counters, but that takes a bit of technical stuff to explain what a Turing machine is.

$x+1/x\ge 2$ if $x > 0$.  Proof: $(\sqrt x-\sqrt{1/x})^2$ must be >=0, so expanding, $(x + {1\over x} - 2) \ge 0$.  Not very deep, but kind of an aha moment in seeing reasoning appear from nowhere and immediately look obvious, getting rid of a calculus problem.

Proof of the triangle inequality in R**n, using Schwarz's inequality.  Again, maybe the proof isn't beautiful in itself, but it was eye-opening in connecting geometry to analysis.

Comment: In reference to your $x + 1/x$ example, I remember seeing the claim advanced somewhere that almost every max–min problem in a standard high-school text is actually an instance of the AMGM inequality in disguise.  Unfortunately, I don't remember the reference ….

Answer (score 1):

I would also like to add a different proof of Fermats little theorem ($p|(a^p-a)$ for prime $p$) to the list.

Suppose you have a colors of pearls and you want to produce pearl-chains of length $p$.

First you put $p$ pearls on a string. There are $a^p$ possibilities.
Next you discard the mono-colored ones, they are boring. This leads to $a^p-a$ choices.

Next you put a knot into the string to turn it to a circular chain.

Now you have each type of chain multiple times, since cyclic permutations give you the same chain.

Finally you have to convince yourself that each type of chain arises in exactly $p$ ways using that $p$ is prime. Thus there are $(a^p-a)/p$ such different chains and hence that number has to be an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Pick up any of the three volumes in Roger Nelsen's *Proofs Without Words* series and turn to any page.  Many of the summation identities mentioned in this thread are included in these books.

Answer (score -1):

If we're going for "beautiful" rather than just "neat", I'd vote for the [Eckmann-Hilton argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eckmann%E2%80%93Hilton_argument). Although it's reasonably abstract for a high-schooler, it should still be quite accessible, and has a lot of "beautiful" symmetry, especially if you look at the nice circle of proofiness.

Comment: Do you really think middle school or high school students will appreciate proving that a monoid is commutative, or the applications to higher homotopy theory? Perhaps I went to the wrong middle school. 

Comment: Depends on the high school students. The assertion is certainly a nice first-round contest-level problem. And it is probably more interesting than many things done in school mathematics (then again, everything is...).

Comment: How compelling do you think this symbol manipulation would be for a wide audience? Say, those who would not understand what you are asking if you ask them to show that a left identity equals a right identity. 

Comment: It seems the question should have been more precise about the level and the interests of the students. But if we are seriously discussing Connes's proof of Morley's theorem, I assumed it to be somewhat above the average.

Answer (score -5):

The following post from the "Everything Seminar" blog would make an excellent lesson in my opinion (link is below). It starts from a simple, but clever "hats puzzle" and then presents an infinite version of the puzzle which is solved (quite amazingly and beautifully) using the axiom of choice. It exemplifies the gap between what we expect to happen and what actually happens which is encountered in mathematics from time to time. Also, you don't really need to introduce any complicated concept, only describe what an equivalence relation is. The mere definition of an equivalence relation is beautiful mathematics in my opinion and the way in which such a simple concept can be used to solve a difficult (impossible?!) problem as above shows how interesting and intriguing mathematics can be.

The relevant post is here:
http://cornellmath.wordpress.com/2007/09/13/the-axiom-of-choice-is-wrong/

Comment: I disagree with, "You don't need to introduce any complicated concept." Do you think the students are already familiar with the Axiom of Choice? They aren't even comfortable with infinite sets. Presenting counterintuitive results which they can't otherwise verify and which are not connected to anything they have seen may be damaging to students new to mathematics. They may well reject mathematics (and at least the AOC) as not sensible, and they may be right unless you are extremely careful in the presentation, much more so than the blog you link, which was not aimed at high school students.

Comment: The axiom of choice seems intuitive to most of us, as are the positive integers (which is the only thing infinite here). I agree that the presentation needs a lot of careful planning, but if the object is to make high school students interested in mathematics, I think that this will achieve this (of course, everyone has a different idea about what mathematics is...).

Comment: The positive integers are not the only infinite set involved in this example. If it were, you wouldn't need to use the Axiom of Choice. You are using the Axiom of Choice on equivalence classes of subsets of the natural numbers.

I really think this example would be damaging. Normally, we start proving things we think are obvious, then prove things we believe, then use proofs to establish the truths of things which are uncertain. These students might or might not have hit the first stage and you want to jump to proving paradoxes with questionable axioms. Students will reject math.

Comment: Also, I disagree that the Axiom of Choice is intuitive. I think it's only intuitive if you overlook what it is really saying, that there exist oracles for situations where we don't have oracles. (The reals can be well-ordered? Ok, tell me how to compare them, or the least element of this set.) You are asking students to accept the step of memorizing the output of an oracle they don't have, but which somehow "exists." This would have turned me off from mathematics. There are much better things to show middle school and high school students than paradoxes which follow from questionable axioms. 

Comment: I agree with Douglas Zare that this topic would not be appropriate for the intended audience.  But I disagree with him abut the axiom of choice "really saying, that there exist oracles for situations where we don't have oracles."  The axiom of choice is about sets, not oracles (unless you take "oracle" to mean simply set), and it certainly isn't about our "having" anything.  After all, we don't even "have" all the natural numbers.  It seems to me that part of the problem with the hats puzzle is that the solution pretends that sets (obtained by AC) can be used as oracles.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification/correction about the oracles vs sets. 