# Math demonstration about friendship between students (not a good title :D)

Tags: co.combinatorics

Some time ago I read this problem:
"In a school there are three classes. In each class there are **n** students. Each student know **n+1** students of the other two classes. Show that there are three students of different classes that know each other."
I struggled for a while trying to solve it, but failed. Then I forgot it and now that I remembered it I can't remember where I've read it.
Is there anyone that have any idea of how to solve this problem? I would appreciate both complete solutions and ideas (maybe with them I can solve it by myself :-) ).
I think it concerns Combinatorics (I've used this tag in this question) but I'm not sure.

PS: if someone know where I could have read it in the first time it would be fantastic, but I doubt it because I read it in Italian. By the way, English is not my first language, so I'm sorry if I've made some mistakes.

Comment: See
"An example of a beautiful proof that would be accessible at the high school level?": http://mathoverflow.net/questions/74841/74859#74859

Comment: Probably this is not suitable fo MO, since it seems rather an undergraduate-level question than a graduate-level or a reserch-level one. As Joseph-O'Rourke suggests, you can translate your problem into a graph-colouring problem. You have three sets A, B, C made of $n$ elements and the complete graphs whose edges connect the elements of A with those of B, the elements of A with those of C and the elements of B with those of C. Color each edge blue or red, according with the fact that the two people represented by the vertices of the edge are strangers or know each other... 

Comment: ...By assumption, from each vertex depart at least $n+1$ red edges. Then try to show that you must have at least a red triangle in your graph

Comment: I don't think $R(3,3)=6$ is of any help in solving this problem.

Comment: @darij: you are right that knowing that $R(3,3)=6$ cannot directly solve this. However, the basic idea in the proof is the same: bi-colouring of graphs, in this specific case 3-partite graphs instead of complete graphs. I stand by my previous comment that this question should be more suitable for a undergraduate forum (like artofproblemsolving) than for MO 

Comment: I still don't see any proof idea in the coloring; isn't it just a rewording of the problem?

Comment: Well, if you like you can call it in this way. But it is a rewording that allows one to use some arguments of geometrical nature ("existence of red triangles") and, in more complicate questions of this kind (e.g. those arising from Ramsey theory),  to use all the techniques and results available in graph theory. However, I agree with you that the language of colouring is not strictly needed in the simple question posed by MathNoob. 

Answer (score 0):

http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?t=40982&ml=1

http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?t=49347&ml=1

And here is a question I'd like to get more attention for: [are there similar results for four (or more) classes where every student knows at least $2n+1$ (resp. all but $n-1$) students from other classes?](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=427146)